# when i install pip install pyaudio its getting error

Tags: python

```
C:\Users\ABC>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Downloading PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ABC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_y3fknpl\\pyaudio_cfd10ebeac564e77949993d585b75b18\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ABC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_y3fknpl\\pyaudio_cfd10ebeac564e77949993d585b75b18\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ue5ei1nt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y3fknpl\pyaudio_cfd10ebeac564e77949993d585b75b18\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ABC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_y3fknpl\\pyaudio_cfd10ebeac564e77949993d585b75b18\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ABC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_y3fknpl\\pyaudio_cfd10ebeac564e77949993d585b75b18\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ue5ei1nt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output
```

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is, and how to fix it.

Comment: **error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/**

Comment: Did that solve your problem...I believe that was just one part of your problem...you will be facing another problem after installing build tools i believe

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you, in the error message, `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required`. You should install it. You haven't indicated that you have or haven't installed it, so if you have, you should specify that that's your issue. It seems like the issue is that you just didn't read the error message though.